# Extending Python with a C++ shared object library using Cython

Tags: c++, python, cython

So basically, I am attempting to write my own GUI wrapper in Python (Using GTK+, but I don't think that's relevant) for an API that is written in C++ and compiled by the user into a shared object file (in linux [*nix? I'm not quite sure how it works on macs]) or a dll (in windows) that you should be able to reference to use the API yourself. After quite a while of trying with Cython, I am able to write my own extensions, as long as it is only a single file, but I can't find anything online about using multiple files (as this obviously is, since any real project would be) to compile into a single .so that can be imported into a Python project. Would I need to manually go through and use Cython and create .pyx files for each .cpp file (there are a lot of them), compile those into cpp files and then edit then use the make file to compile those into the .so file, or is there a more automated way? (p.s. I tried compiling each one separately with Cython, but it didn't seem to like the "#include < path/file >" notation and so couldn't compile most of the files)

Other info: I have been able to interface with the library using ctypes, but that felt extremely hackish and un-pythonic, and I want to get some more experience with Cython anyways, since it seems like it could be an extremely useful asset to have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a file named "yourmodule.pyx", rename all the others files to pxi, and do:

```
include "other1.pxi"
include "other2.pxi"
```

Then you'll have only one file to cythonize and compile: yourmodule.pyx.

Comment: That's a neat idea. However, what I ended up doing was creating a C++ file that merely interacted directly with the .so file and then just wrapped that into it's own separate extension (An extension who's sole purpose is to talk to another extension). Overall it's been very successful. Thanks though.